# Does there exists an analytic function $f$ such that $f (\frac1n) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\; \forall n = 1, 2, 3\ldots?$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Does there exists an analytic function $f$ on the unit disc $D =  D_1(0)$ such that $f (\frac1n) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\; \forall n = 1, 2,
>  3\ldots ?$

Let $g(z) = z^2$, and $S = \{\frac1{2k} \; |\; k\in \mathbb{Z}^+\} \subset D$

Also, let $h(z) = f(z) - g(z)$

then $\forall z\in S\rightarrow h(z) = f(z) - g(z) = 0$

Now, $0 $ is a limit point of $S$ and $S\subset D$, so by the identity theorem $h = 0 $ on $D$ $\rightarrow f = g $ on $D$

But clearly, for $\frac13 \in D$  $f(\frac13) = -\frac{1}9 \neq \frac19 = g(\frac13)$

So, we cannot have such an analytic function $f$

Comment: Your argument is correct. Such a function cannot exist.

Comment: @Crostul thank you.